# Travis CI nodejs 4 and eval npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci

I m building an electron application with Node V4.4.3 and I need to build it using travis CI.

Actually, my Travis CI looks like this :

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "4"
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8
after_script:
  - cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js
```

According to travis, it seems that the build is okay one time per day (see [#12](https://travis-ci.org/Skahrz/google-search-bar/builds/132473136) and [#8](https://travis-ci.org/Skahrz/google-search-bar/builds/132276799))

In other cases, it seems that the **npm install** command fails displaying me errors like :

> The command "eval npm install " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.

And the process is killed because of timeout (after ~40 mns)

Any idea of what happens ?

Comment: Does verbose mode helps ? DEBUG=electron-builder ([i guess](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/src/util.ts#L16))

Answer (score 0):

Please check the discussion in [this](https://github.com/hapijs/university/issues/143) issue on github. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please downgrade the version of grunt to grunt": "^0.4.5

As npm 2 doesn't support grunt version : 1.0.0

$ npm --version
2.15.11

so for this dependencies should be :-

"devDependencies": 
{
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-install": "^1.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-maven-tasks": "^1.4.0",                                               "grunt-npm-install": "^0.3.1"
}